# Nginx cache static files from different aplications

Tags: caching, nginx

I use WordPress as a home page (mysite.com) and Django for the rest (mysite.com/pages). I have single nginx config file for both of them and its working fine. Moreover, they reside in a single `server` block.

Here are some parts of my configuration:

```
server {
    ...
    root /var/www/wordpress;
    ...
    location /static/ {
        alias  /home/username/Env/virtenv/mysite/static/;
    }
}
```

With this both WordPress and Django static files are served.
Now I want to cache all static files for 7 days in the browser. If I put this in addition:

```
location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|svg|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
    expires 7d;
}
```

then the WordPress static files are properly cached, but Django's static files are not even served.

I know this is because the `/static/` location is never reached and then Nginx searched Django's files in the `root` directive which is on `server` block level and which points to the WordPress location.

I can remove the cache location and add `expires 7d;` in the /static/ `location`. This will in opposite cache only the static files of Django.

But how can I make both static resources to be cached for a week?

Comment: I put `expires 7d;` into `/static/` and result is still the same. Nginx does not serve the resources in `/static/` because if searches them in `location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png`.

Comment: Would you share what kind of alternative solution you can propose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I was able to cache both static files - of Wordpress and Django.
For requests starting with `/static/`, I found a way to make Nginx use the `/static/` `location` and not the general static files `location`, which has the purpose to only cache Wordpress static files.

Its so simple: just use the location modifier `^~`.

As this wonderful article of [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms) says:

> The block modifier `^~` means that if this block is selected as the best non-regular expression match, regular expression matching will not take place.

Here is the working version of the two location blocks:

```
location ~*  \.(?:jpg|jpeg|png|svg|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
    # Cache Wordpress or any other public static files
    # of those types for a week in the browser
    expires 7d;
}

location ^~ /static/ {
    alias  /home/username/Env/virtenv/mysite/static/;
    # Cache Django's static files for a week in the browser
    expires 7d;
}
```

All requests with `mysite.com/static/...` will match the /static/ location and will not continue to any other regex location.

And for example requests as `mysite.com/wp-content/themes/a-theme/style.css?ver=4.7.2`
will match the regex location.